# not able to find which column validation getting failed in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We have around 92 columns in a single `table`. Same data we are getting from `JSON`. now due to missing validation user is able to enter anything on the text field and we are getting below error.

```
 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

We have checked even in log we are not getting `which column throwing this error`. is there any better way to find which `column` in `Oracle` throwing this error. We are using `hibernate` as ORM tool.

Answer (score 1):

Error is related to `NUMBER` datatype *family* (including aliases, such as `int` or `decimal`).

Check how you declared these columns in a table; maybe the *simplest* way to fix it is to declare them just as `NUMBER` (no precision, no scale) which then allows numbers with maximum precision and scale.

Otherwise, if you want to pinpoint the column, you'll have to - as far as I can tell - parse input data and validate each column separately.